# Uniqueness of Analytic Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I wasn't very well introduced to Analytic Continuations, but from what I have seen, showing that the analytic continuation is unique is pretty simple. In Real Analysis, from what I can imagine, there isn't a unique analytic continuation of a function, is that true? If so, why is it that we can so easily restrict the continuation of a *complex* function to be one and only one thing?

Comment: The identity theorem relies on the complex differentiability. The real question is as to whether the function is *analytic*, not just differentiable. In the complex case, the two are synonymous. Not so in the real case.

Comment: In real analysis, are analytic continuations of analytic functions unique?

Comment: See _unique continuation_ in [this](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Real_analytic_function).

Comment: @AdamHughes Can you point me to a proof that an analytic function (over reals) need not be differentiable. Is analytic same as continuous? (My math teachers were terrible)

Comment: @jus12 analytic means it has a power series. Necessarily this converges uniformly on compact sets, hence you can differentiate term by term. This implies differentiability in all cases.

Comment: @jus12 Note there is no contradiction:  I said the two were not synonymous, one implies the other in both cases, only in the complex case are they equivalent.